# How to use JSON in PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing an application in android using PhoneGap. I want to use rest JSON in my code to call web service, unable to find any solution. I guess XUI is used for calling web service in PhoneGap, but didnot find the way how to use XUI in PhoneGap.If possible please tell me steps and sample code. please help...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To use XHR, must all the code (PhoneGap source if used as web application) be residing on the same server as the web service? OR Can I call an external web service from the Javascript of the html page using XHR?

Comment: Phonegap applications can make ajax requests to any server. The only constraint is that ios apps have a whitelist in a .plist file that your domains must be in. To allow all domains just use `*`. In my experience, Android phonegap by default allows any URL already.

Comment: @iolo thanks for the suggestion. I tried calling a few public web services that provide JSON response like googleplus and others. It worked great when I called the web service from Javascript in the phonegap's html file. I think it's only AJAX that cannot access web services outside the same domain; JSON does not have this problem to a large extent I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You should be reading the documentation for XUI then:

http://xuijs.com/

http://xuijs.com/docs/xhr

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use JQuery ajax like in usual web development? I tested this recently with PhoneGap and it works.